# Web chart Javascript graphing library showing trend lines

Tags: javascript, web, trending

Does anyone know of a Javascript graph drawing library that also supports rendering of trend lines out of the 'box'.
The only way I've seen trend lines implemented is by pre-calculating the trend yourself and passing this series to the chart.
Do any libraries support this?

Comment: I do not quite get, what you mean by "rendering of trend lines" ootB: Maybe http://www.highcharts.com/ is of some help.

Comment: I meant will the library draw trend lines for me when I just tell it the start and end points, rather than me working out the points of the trend.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/) its works really well as a charting tool and I believe there are plugins available for automatic trendlines, of the top of my head I remember [highcharts_trendline](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline), but I'm pretty sure there are more.